# android:background="@null" (or some color) vs no android:background results in weird behaviour

Tags: android-imagebutton

I've got this piece of XML:

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_left"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/leftarrow"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_up"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/uparrow"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_down"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"

            android:src="@drawable/downarrow"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_right"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:src="@drawable/rightarrow"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

With this result in design preview:
[image]

So, I prefer the Down and Right buttons, because it changes color of area around arrows to dark gray when the ImageButtons are pressed.

However, I'd like to set the backgroundColor to something different from Gray and I want to keep the size of the arrows just like in the Down and Right buttons.

Not only do I not understand where the light gray areas around the arrows come from (the original Drawable .png background is white), but I also do not understand why simply adding the background to null changes the arrow size and eliminates the light gray area. Please enlighten me regarding this issue.

Another annoying thing is the padding inside the buttons; how to get rid of it?